# How to get a specific attribute from a tag in react (from generated html)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is quite a specific issue I'm having so I am hoping someone can help me out.

I am generating a QR code via SVG method in Bacon QR Code generator (Laravel) and it generates something along the lines of this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#fefefe"/>
<g transform="scale(4.082)"><g transform="translate(4,4)">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="DATA GOES HERE" fill="#000000" />
</g></g>
```

Where it says 'DATA GOES HERE' is the generated data that makes up the QR code. I used a call in my React component to the back end to generate this, then I tried putting it into a state which I would then display in the block I created, but it just literally renders this as plain text. After some testing I saw that I can add the data to the state and then implement it in the path element like so:

```
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d={ this.state.qrCodeData } fill="#000000" />
```

However, getting just that data is proving difficult. Basically what I'm asking is, is there a way to pluck out the attribute 'd' from the 'path' element in React, but from the above SVG code that's generated from the back end?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make either option work. To render the svg as html and not plaintext, you would use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You should only do this if you trust the SVG. Otherwise, to grab just the `d`, you could use a regex. It's definitely safe, and depending on what your data is could work perfectly well. If your SVG plaintext is stored as `svgString`, you could do something like: `svgString[svgString.search(/g="[^"]*"/g)];`. It's a little icky, but at least doesn't open you up to XSS attacks.

Comment: I forgot about dangerouslySetInnerHtml actually! I have used regex in the past but I'm not a fan. Thanks for your help!